# Handling RLMResult in heterogeneous table view

Tags: ios, realm

How should I handle a table view whose cells represent both a `RLMResult` and other custom views?
Say I have this structure, a todo list app that shows items of todo list and some ads:

```swift
protocol TableItem {}

class ToDoItem: RLMObject, TableItem {
 // properties
}

class Advertising: TableItem {
 // properties
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var result: RLMResult<ToDoItem>
var ads: [Advertising]

var tableViewItems: [TableItem] // Created by mixing both `result` and `ads`.

}

// other class stuff
```

I have to dequeue a different cell based on the the type of each item in `tableViewItems`.

The simplest thing would be to convert the `result` property to a simple `Array<ToDoItem>` and then concatenate both arrays; Realm documentation discourages to convert a `RLMResult` to a simple array to avoid losing all lazy features of `RLMResult`.

Any idea?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. A tableViewCell is a tableViewCell. You can subclass it, add different objects to it but it's still a cell. Are these different cells within the same column? If so, how about just making one container cell and have it display different objects - they could even be subviews of different objects? Can you clarify the question?

Comment: You might want to explain the use case. But based on what you've said so far this does not sound like a good idea. If you convert to an array you won't be able to take advantage of realm notifications. However, I'm even more concerned about why you'd want to mix two different types in your data source.

Comment: I don’t see any wrong in mixing two different types in same data source as I want to display different things in the same table view. For example I have a todo list and some ads between the items.

Comment: As @Rob mentioned, Realm results are heterogeneous so you actually can't mix two types of data. If you 'convert' it to an array, you will loose the automatic updating of your realm objects. Generally, you would have a cellView subclass that can handle a variety of UI elements - it could be populated with text in one row, text + image in another and then just an image in another row (like an ad). But again, is this a single column case or multiple columns? I think the question needs more context to be answerable.

Comment: @RicoCrescenzio I don't think you have any option but to convert your realm dataset to an array and weave each ToDoItem element with your Advertising elements. It's not ideal, but you are going to have to make some sacrifices. This an atypical requirement.